# TortoiseSVN - I've changed package name in Eclipse - Can't see in SVN

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn

So I've changed package name in Eclipse. I was expecting to see status rename or deleted and see bunch of unversioned files - unfortunelty I don't see them, it's like they are ignored or non-existing for turtle. When I created repository in other folder - still the same.

I had `com.abc.dfg.aaa` and I've changed it to `eu.xzx.dfg.aaa`.
I can see all untill I get to folder `java` (inside there's folder `pl` which is unvisible from that part for TortoiseSVN).

Any ideas? My google skills haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have Subversion client installed in the Eclipse, then renaming package will result in simple filesystem move instead of `svn move` operation.

Try to install one of the following before renaming of the package:

- http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/
- http://subclipse.tigris.org/